# Pyodbc error: 08004 - Server rejected the connection

Tags: python, pyodbc, ibm-soliddb

I am new to python and SolidDB. I would like to seek help about the error that I'm getting. Although the credentials are right (I think), still I am rejected by the server. Here is the stack trace.

```
[root@DW700 standalone]# python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 28 2014, 03:45:51)
[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=SolidDB;SERVER=tcp 1964;DATABASE=dba;PWD=password')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('08004', '[08004] [unixODBC]Server rejected the connection (14505) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SERVER parameter does not look right. Try something like `SERVER=hostname,PORT=1964` or `hostname:1964` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPK3V_7.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.admin.doc/doc/encryption.authentication.troubleshooting.connectreject.html) you can see that probably the credentials are wrong.